# JavaFX WebView displays empty page using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm trying to display a website inside a JavaFX WebView component but it only renders an empty page. I've setup everything as follows:

MainController.java

```
public class MainController extends Application
{
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Pane pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        // ... Some proxy config here ...
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Desmon");
        initRootLayout();
    }

    public void initRootLayout()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainController.class.getResource("../view/Main.fxml"));
            pane = (Pane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            MainViewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage()
    {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainViewController.java

```
public class MainViewController
{
    @FXML
    private WebView webTEA;

    private MainController main;

    public MainViewController()
    {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        webTEA = new WebView();
        WebEngine we = webTEA.getEngine();
        we.load("http://this/is/my/url.php");
    }

    public void setMain(MainController main)
    {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

Main.fxml

```
<Pane minHeight="500.0" minWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.MainViewController">
```

and

```
<children>
    <WebView fx:id="webTEA" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="417.0" prefWidth="570.0" />
</children>
```

As you can see I've also setup some proxy settings with `System.setProperty()`. I also tried it without specific proxy settings - I think this is not the problem.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I launch the application I can see the WebView component, but there is no content. I can only right-click and see a "Reload"-item in the context menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a normal url (like http://stackoverflow.com) without the security settings does it work? Have you tried looking at the log output if you start your application with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: Thank. The problem was that I was not using the WebView that was injected by the FXMLLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `WebView` instead of using the one created and injected by the `FXMLLoader`. Just remove

```
webTEA = new WebView();
```

from the `initialize` method to use the existing `WebView`. Otherwise you initialize a new `WebView` instance that is never added to the scene graph.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that was a way too obvious. Thank you, it's working now!